# input field text not changing

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to change input field text, that uses javascript onblur and onfocus , but after saving it. I don't see any changes. Following is the code

```
<input type="text" name="EMAIL" class="required email" value="<?php _e('email','woothemes'); ?>"  id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('email','woothemes'); ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('email','woothemes'); ?>';}">
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="EMAIL" class="required email" value="<?php _e('your@email.com','woothemes'); ?>"  id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('your@email.com','woothemes'); ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('your@email.com','woothemes'); ?>';}">
```

as the term `<?php _e(); ?>` is used for translation in wordpress, i changed it to echo and even then, i don't see any changes. 
Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you try removing the PHP and setting the value blank to see if that changes it ?

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GwMGx/1/) -- Not with PHP but static values! i'm not sure but you are pursuing dynamic placholder!

Comment: Please share generated html code

Comment: @Fallen this is the generated code `<input id="mce-EMAIL" class="required email" type="text" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-mail';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'E-mail') {this.value = '';}" value="E-mail" name="EMAIL">`

Answer (score 0):

```
onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e('your@email.com','woothemes'); ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e('your@email.com','woothemes'); ?>';}">
                           ^_________^              ^__^        ^_____^
```

Note the range of single quotes in the code segment Try this instead,

```
onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php _e(\"your@email.com\",\"woothemes\"); ?>') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '<?php _e(\"your@email.com\",\"woothemes\"); ?>';}">
```

Comment: Doesn't matter what quotes you use inside the PHP tags, it's not outputted anyway!

Comment: @adeneo: my bad, didn't notice. Waiting for the generated html from OP or will delete this